# I can't get this canvas to fill a rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
       <title>sdssd</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="area">
      </canvas>
   </body>
   <footer>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
   </footer>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#area {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto 30%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS: All of this is pretty bare bones, i simply want to draw a shape (for now) but context.fillRrect doesn't seem to be working... i don't know why tho

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle("red");
context.fillRect(4, 5, 132, 132);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
context.fillStyle("red");
```

to

```
context.fillStyle = "red";
```

to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/t0yqm6jb/

Comment: Damn, it worked, thanks alot Laurens. I don't know why the console didn't put up a warning or something.